# Position Logo in line with site title in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, header

I have in my header.php the following code. What I want to do is to position the logo with the text so that it stays there when it is viewed on a smaller device aswell.  I am using the foundationpress theme on wordpress to do this. The title seems to dissappear when I insert the logo before it but if I insert the logo after the title its viewed fine :

```
<div class="top-bar-container contain-to-grid show-for-medium-up" role="navigation">
<nav class="top-bar" data-topbar role="navigation">
    <ul class="title-area">

<li class="name">
<a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>"><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></a>
<img src="http://localhost/rabbit/wp-content/themes/FoundationPress-master/images/flogo.svg"     width="80" height="80">

</li>

    </ul>
    <section class="top-bar-section">
        <?php foundationPress_top_bar_l(); ?>
        <?php foundationPress_top_bar_r(); ?>
    </section>
   </nav>
 </div>
```

Comment: Can you show us a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) of this, or a live site?  It's almost certainly down to styling/CSS, but you haven't shown us any, so it's difficult for us to help.

Comment: I'm not sure your question is clear, what is exactly the problem: the title is not aligned? it's not showing? where it should be placed, before or after the logo? your last line says "the title is viewd fine" which adds more confusion.

Comment: all am saying is I want the  title first and then the logo. Its working fine the opposite way around which I dont want. How can I CSS the image to position it @mikemike

Comment: Like I said, we will need to see a working example in order to help.  My thoughts are you probably have some CSS there already which is causing you problems.

Comment: Post your CSS. How can we tell you what's wrong with the CSS when you haven't posted any. Even better, post a live example like the URL to the page, or a jsFiddle replicating the issue.